# PHP: get current array key?

Tags: php, search, arrays, recursion, find

```
$array = ( 
    array('1231415'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 1)),
    array('32434'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> '0')),
    array('123244'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 0)),
    array('193928'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 1))
);
```

I have an array that has (many) random keys, the ID number. I need to test each array within if 'test' = 1, and so I made a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($array as $sub) {
  if ($sub['test'] == '1' ) {
     echo 'User: ' . $sub . ' has test = 1';
  }
}
```

This works, but it returns 'User: Array has test = 1'

How on earth to I get which ID number, (that random number) has test=1 in it?

I tried doing `$array as $sub=>$value`, but for some reason it just makes the `foreach` not work. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054661/php-high-depth-array-how-do-return-current-key-name ?

Comment: I tried what answer #1 suggested, but it just returns:
>[0] => User: Array has in_env = 1
>[1] => User: Array has in_env = 1

Comment: So you don't use that answer... wait for someone else to come along with a new answer. Don't need another question.

Answer (score 11):

Use this `foreach` syntax instead:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $sub) {
  if ($sub['test'] == '1' ) {
    echo 'User: ' . $key . ' has test = 1';
  }
}
```

This assumes that the data is in the form:

```
$array = array(
  '1234' => array('test' => 1),
  '5678' => array('test' => 2)
);
```

If you need to keep your data as it is now, you'll need to use something more like:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  list($key, $info) = $item;
  if ($info['test'] == 1) {
    echo 'User: ' . $key . ' has test = 1';
  }
}
```

Comment: this isn't actually correct, considering the array structure he has here.

Comment: You're right - I've updated it both with an alternate data format and with a solution that will match the current data format.

Comment: @pix0r: Your 3rd code snippet won't work for him because his array definition has a syntax error.

Comment: Hah, ok.. he needs to add an `array` on the first line before the first open paren.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1) Your array declaration is slightly messed up. Try this:

```
$array = array( 
   '1231415'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 1),
   '32434'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 0),
   '123244'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 0),
   '193928'=>array('foo'=>'bar', 'test'=> 1)
);
```

2) In your `foreach`, you're losing the id key. Try this:

```
foreach ($array as $id => $sub) {
    if ($sub['test'] == 1) {
        echo "User: " . $id . " has test = 1\n";
    }
}
```

In my test the above outputs:

```
User: 1231415 has test = 1
User: 193928 has test = 1
```